# curl_exec() argument removing last 2 digit of integer

Tags: php, web-services

I'm using softtouch API with WordPress, and posting data to API via curl.

But in response I am not able to send the big integer value in function. I'm not getting is that data type range issue or curl.

Below is my code:

```
//create reservation
$prod_items = array();
$single_item = array('product_uid'=>11449701010101);
$prod_items[] = $single_item;

$res_params = array(
    'customer_id' => 1111,
    'payment_type' => '',
    'invoice_address_id' => 123,
    'delivery_address_id' => 142,
    'giftlist_id' => '',
    'store_id' => '',
    'items' => $prod_items
);
$res_url = $base_url . 'reservations';    
$res_content = json_encode($res_params);

$res_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($res_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: ' . $authToken, 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($res_curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($res_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $res_content);
curl_setopt($res_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $res_url);
curl_setopt($res_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$res_response = curl_exec($res_curl);

if ($res_response === FALSE)
die(curl_error($res_curl));
curl_close($res_curl);
$res_array = json_decode($res_response);
```

While sending data to the `curl_exec()` function it removes the last two digits of the `product_uid`, as I passed it `11449701010101` it send it as `114497010101`.

Is that any integer range issue or something curl function issue?

Answer (score 0):

**tl:dr** There would seem to be *something else* (in the script that processes the CURL request) that is truncating the `product_uid`. (?)

> ```
> array('product_uid'=>11449701010101)
> ```

If you are on a 32 bit system (PHP compiled as 32 bit) then `11449701010101` does exceed the 32 bit integer range. However, in such cases, PHP *silently* converts the number to a *float* and nothing is "lost" in this instance.

> ```
> json_encode($res_params);
> ```

The PHP function `json_encode()` converts the passed array into a string respresentation (JSON string). Nothing is lost. The `11449701010101` value is preserved.

> While sending data to the `curl_exec()` function it removes the last two digits

The (POST) data being transmitted is an ordinary string, so nothing can be lost to the individual properties at this stage.

If the receiving script then decodes the transmitted JSON string, encodes it again and sends it back, the data is returned intact. The `product_uid` is a float, not an integer (as it is in the original data).

If you specifically force `11449701010101` to an integer (eg. `(int)11449701010101`) then you get `-681801035` - the last 2 digits are not simply truncated. For the last 2 digits to be truncated there would seem to be some kind of string manipulation going on?

So, there would seem to be something else (not shown here) during the processing of this data that is perhaps truncating the value. (?)